# Compare each item in list with a value and return T/F in Python

Tags: python, list

I have a list `a = [3,5,2,3,1]` and I want to check whether each item in this list is no less than 3.

I tried `a >= 3`, but it has TypeError.

`TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'list' and 'int'`

Desired output [True, True, False, True, False]

Comment: Look up `map()` function or `list` comprehension, it's great for your scenario.

Comment: I cannot believe that you researched that problem and haven't found anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `map`

```
>>> list(map((3).__le__, [3,6,2,3,1]))
[True, True, False, True, False]
```

or `numpy`

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.less_equal(3, [3,5,2,3,1])
array([ True,  True, False,  True, False], dtype=bool)
```

or `numpy`

```
>>> 3 <= np.array([3,5,2,3,1])
array([ True,  True, False,  True, False], dtype=bool)
```

Actually, I'd recommend `numpy` since it seems to match your way of thinking.

Answer (score 4):

Use a list comprehension:

```
a = [3,5,2,3,1]
new_a = [i >= 3 for i in a]
print(new_a)
```

Output:

```
[True, True, False, True, False]
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to test each element than

```
a = [3,5,2,3,1]
print map(lambda x: x>=3, a)
```

**output**
[True, True, False, True, False]

Or just want to verify all elements passed through your condition

```
print reduce(lambda b, n: b and n>= 3, a)
```

**output**
False